# See changes from nested repositories in Source Control in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to configure VS Code to show changes from multiple repositories?

I have following structure:

```
- Repository 1 (git repo)
|- src
|- test
|- ...
|- Widgets (git repo)
   |- src
   |- test
   |- ...
```

Both `Repository 1` and `Widgets` have `.git` folder. In "Source control" I can see only changes from `Repository 1`, but not `Widgets`.

Also in "Source control - Source Control Providers" I can see only `Repository 1`.

[image: VS Code Source control]

I tried to configure the both `Repository 1` and `Widgets` as work space folders, but it didn't help. In [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension I see both repos independently, but cannot commit from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now nested repositories are not supported out of the box. There is already an issue on GitHub - [Git: Support nested git repositories](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37947).

Check out the issue for some workarounds on this, like adding folders in reverse (inner folders first) into workspace or using `.gitmodules`. Also give it some buzz so that it hopefully get implemented.

Answer (score 7):

An update on the issue reported by @mimo in his answer.  It has been closed as completed and the changes will be in vscode v1.72.  From [1.72 Release Notes: discover nested git repositories](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#discover-nested-git-repositories):

> #### Discover nested git repositories
>
> Addressing a long standing feature request, this milestone we have
> made changes to the repository discovery code in order to add sup port
> for nested git repositories. Depending on the location of the nested
> repositories, one may need to modify the `git.repositoryScanMaxDepth`
> setting.

Comment: Thanks for the info! For VS Code 1.81.1, just setting `git.autoRepositoryDetection` to `subFolders` wasn't enough, and I had to set `git.repositoryScanMaxDepth` and restart VS Code as well

Comment: After setting `repositoryScanMaxDepth`, I needed to restart vscode, (classic microsoft procedure).
No need to add .gitmodules file in subfolders