# VS Code - Multi-root workspace not showing all git repositories in source control panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a multi-root workspace set up where all of the folders in my workspace are git repositories.

However, for some reason only some of them show up in the Source Control panel, even though I've added them all to the workspace in the same way (`File` > `Add Folder to Workspace`).

**How do I get all of the repositories to show up in the Source Control panel?**

---

This is what my workspace looks like:

[image: workspace folders]

This is what my source control looks like:

[image: source control repositories]

Comment: I tried the two answers below, but had to use the recommendation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73938264/1919793 to get this to work on my repo

Answer (score 7):

I just had this happen to me, but for a different reason. I had three repos but only two showed up on the GIT tab:

[image]

[image]

Just on a hunch, I right clicked in the source control area on the left VSCode panel, then clicked the "Repositories" option in the drop-down menu and saw that the repo in question wasn't selected:

[image]

Once I selected the "interfaces" repo in the drop-down menu (so that it was checked), it then appeared in the source control area.

I've been using multi-root workspaces for a while and this never happened to me before, so I don't know what I did to cause it, but it's an easy thing to check for.

Comment: After I had added another repo dir to a long list of them in project.code-workspace, suddenly many repos were "unchecked". I verified there was no syntax error. I removed what I added and they all came back. With this answer I redid the change again, and manually checked the repos, and all is well.

Answer (score 4):

For me, this issue ended up being a folder permissions issue. I ran VS Code as administrator and the missing directories showed up. I looked at the directory owners and noticed the working directories were own by my user, and the non working directories were owned by the admin group (which my user belonged to). Changing the directory ownership to my main user was the long term fix.

two out rabbit hole. Meh.

Comment: WOW! This has to be a VSCode bug (V1.70.2).  I have multi-root workspace with 13 folders. I have 9 of these as source repositories (TFS git & GitHub). Missing repo fixed after I changed folder ownership (recursively) from Administrators to my user, then closed/restarted VSCode (as user). <br>  (system setup)
Date: 2022-08-16T05:35:13.448Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

Answer (score 0):

Neither worked for me, and I had to instead trigger a command `ctrl + shift + p`, and choose "Git: Reopen closed repositories"